# get time remaining for morning

Tags: php, time

I am trying to get remain time for morning 8 AM,

I tried this:

```
$hours = current_time('H');

$now = current_time( 'timestamp' );
$tomorrow = strtotime('tomorrow +8Hours', current_time( 'timestamp' ));

floor(($tomorrow - $now) / (60 * 60)) ;
```

but in morning, it shift to tomorrows date.

Please tell me how do I get remaining time (in hour) for morning 8 AM. After 8 AM count tomorrow morning.

Thanks.

Comment: What else have you tried? Isn't this expected if you always do `"tomorrow +8Hours"` no matter what?

Comment: What is `current_time`? Btw, programming is about translating algorithms from human language to code. How would you explain the steps that need to be performed by some human to get the result? Like: 1. Take the current time 2. Extract the hour part 3. If ... 4 ....

Comment: @kingkero dont you see in my question ? `floor(($tomorrow - $now) / (60 * 60)) ;`

Comment: I keep re-reading this and I still don't know what you're looking for. Can you try to explain this in more detail?

Comment: @JohnConde I guess OP wants the remaining time to (next) 8am. If 10pm -> 10hrs, 4am -> 4hrs. But since he is measuring it to "tomorrow's 8am": 4am -> 28hrs

Answer (score 2):

You can create two [`DateTime`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php) objects and calculate the difference between the two using [`DateTime::diff()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php):

```
$now = new DateTime();
$eight = new DateTime('08:00:00');

if ($now->format('H:i:s') > '08:00:00') {
  $eight->modify('+1 day');
}

$interval = $eight->diff($now);

echo $interval->format('%H:%I:%S');
```